# How to change Title bar favicon Icon in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, favicon

I want to change the title bar favicon Icon in Drupal? I'm new in Drupal. I'm using Bartik Theme.

Answer (score 0):

Appearance >> Settings

```
/admin/appearance/settings
```

[image]

OR place favicon.ico into the theme root folder.